# Require questions to pass a spell-checker

Tags: feature-request, spelling

Right now writing proper English is optional instead of mandatory. As a result, there are a lot of questions here that have:

- Awful grammar.
- Spelling errors.
- Txtspeak - using 'u' instead of 'you'.
- Lack of capitalization - 'i' instead of 'I'.
- Missing/wrong punctuation.

It would be great if the site would require posts to first pass a spell checker before accepting the submission. It could even highlight the first error and give hints how to fix it.

Code sections would be exempted, of course, which would incidentally force people to actually put their code in code sections. There is also inline code, so you could accept `i` but not i.

Comment: While we're at it, we should enforce that all code posted should compile cleanly.

Comment: If such a proposed spellchecker were in place, you wouldn't have been able to submit this _proposal_.

Comment: Good thing that there's `no way` to put `non-code` words inside of `code` blocks to `get` around `this check`.

Comment: @Oded Not only compile clean, but execute in `O(1)` time.

Comment: What if the community could **edit** such questions and fix the grammatical and spelling issues? Crazy notion, I know.

Comment: i am nat shore Y U wud do dat

Comment: Would that imply that I would never be able to search for `foobar` in a string?

Comment: @Oded That would require people to waste their time editing posts written by someone who was too lazy to write properly. The spell-checker would force them to put some effort themselves.

Comment: What we really need is a mechanism to automatically identify good questions from bad ones. If it's a good question, automatically fix all the spelling/grammar/formatting errors. If it's a bad question, close it... Wait... am I asking too much?

Comment: @sashoalm And all of the people who are using entirely valid text that happens to not pass a spell checker be damned?

Comment: @Mysticial Well, then how do spell checkers manage to sort out good text from bad? MS Word seems to catch all my spelling and grammar mistakes. I doubt they've implemented AI secretly :)

Comment: @Servy Perhaps their text is not so valid then? I'm assuming they've put their code in code sections or inline code.

Comment: @sashoalm There is more to a good question than spelling everything right.

Comment: Sounds like another case of "what's good for me is good for everyone else".

Comment: @Mysticial we could use that AI to also answer those good questions right away

Comment: @sashoalm Dictionaries are incomplete, often don't contain highly specialized technical terms, etc.  There are plenty of entirely valid reasons to have words not in a standard dictionary outside of code blocks in an SE post.

Comment: Artificial intelligence is no match for human stupidity -- _Anonymous_

Comment: So you're also proposing that we remove the [mysql] tag, since nobody will be able to say "MySQL" in a question any more?

Comment: @Doorknob Why? Can't StackOverflow have a custom dictionary that includes all the technical slang? Or would that be too clever?

Comment: @sashoalm You can't possibly hope to catalog *every single* programming term used *ever*....

Comment: @sashoalm There's no way for such a dictionary to be complete, and to include all of the new technical terms that come out on a daily basis.  It would be a *huge* amount of work, and likely end up with users either [subverting this mechanism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228817/require-questions-to-pass-a-spell-checker#comment750484_228817) in some way, or simply leaving because we make it excruciatingly hard to post perfectly fine questions.

Comment: @Doorknob See, people will still be able to use backticks to say `MySQL`, and things like "I tried to `decompile` the file but the `decompiler` gave me a `well-formedness` error" or "I'm writing an algorithm to produce the `ergative` forms of blah." Or "I was trying to parse the `absolutive` form of the `deverbative`." (In case that was not clear: I agree with your objection.)

Comment: Requiring proper grammar and spelling means most people who are not native speakers will have a really difficult time posting anything - I cannot see how this can be a positive thing.

Comment: > If you want to, e.g., frob a warble, in C you would write it as `frob(warble)`, or maybe you want to frob a warble by reference and you write `frob(&warble)`, but in C# you would likely write `warble.Frob()` instead.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranthl, Mystical that sort of AI is too hard.  Maybe there's some 'mechanical turk'-style system that we could use to check posts and provide answers...

Answer (score 7):

But then everything would look like this:

> I have some Python code to intact with a `MySQL` database, but I don't think it's `Pythonic`. The creator of Python, `Guido`, says that running code from a `JS` `bookmarklet` isn't good, but I disagree. I am also using `Delphi`. If I run this from a `cronjob`, how can I `decompile` my code? `Befunge` isn't an `esolang` anymore!

Is that somehow an improvement? The edit system is there for a reason; use it.